# How to define a global method whose variables can be used in other methods in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm working on an automation project. I am automating the login page. There is a problem with the login page in the website that I'm working on, i.e, it fails the first time I log in, even if the credentials are correct, and then successfully logs in if I log in the second time. So, to overcome this I have included a try except for method. The code:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\temp\\chromedriver.exe")
url = 'site-address'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120)

class Demo
    def func1()
        user=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//")
        user.send_keys('Name')
        pas = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//")
        password.send_keys('pas')
        btn = driver .find_element_by_xpath("//")
        btn.click()

        try:
            chk=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'lop')))
            assert check.text == "Some Text"
            print('PAGE VERIFIED : ', check.text)
        except:
            print('LOGIN UN-SUCCESSFUL')
            print('Re-Trying...')
            user=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//")
            user.send_keys('Name')
            pas = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//")
            pas.send_keys('pas')
            btn = driver .find_element_by_xpath("//")
            btn.click()
```

So, as you can see I am repeating the process of entering username, password and click twice, once in the beginning and then the same process in the except block. My question is, how to create a method, call it setup() such that I can initialize the driver, URL, username, password in setup(). And then call the method in func1() and then in the except block. I'm new to Python, not familiar how to return the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python classes have a constructor called `__init__` which you can use to pass information to when creating an object of this class. Something like this, even if the separation of logic is not the best. But gives you an idea of the constructor.

```
class Demo:

    def __init__(self, driver, url, username, password):
        """ Constructor of our demo class, set local variables"""
        self.driver = driver
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver.get(url)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 120)

    def func1(self, attempt=1):
        """ Find elements in the opened page and send username and pasword,
        then clikc the button (submit?) """
        user = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//")
        user.send_keys(self.username)
        pas = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//")
        pas.send_keys(self.password)
        btn = driver .find_element_by_xpath("//")
        btn.click()

        try:
            # Wait for element
            chk = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'lop')))
            assert chk.text == "Some Text"
            print('PAGE VERIFIED : ', chk.text)
        except:
            # General exception ..
            if attempt >= 3: # Start with 1.. so 1, 2, 3.
                print("FAILED THREE TIMES, GIVING UP")
            else:
                print('LOGIN UN-SUCCESSFUL')
                print('Re-Trying...')
                self.func1(attempt + 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\temp\\chromedriver.exe")
    url = 'site-address'
    TEST = Demo(driver=driver, url=url, username='Name', password='pas')
    TEST.func1()
```